# Xcode compiler error, but iOS program compiles

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am calling the code below in a C++ class.

```
void CurrentClass::doSomeProcessing() {
      printf("Hello World");
}

void CurrentClass::someMethod() {
      std::thread t(&CurrentClass::doSomeProcessing, this);
}
```

It seems that Xcode IDE throws the following error.

```
No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'
```

But, the program compiles and runs without an issue.

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?

I am guessing it is some setting in the build settings for my Xcode project??

Comment: My code does compile though, the ide seems to be throwing an error though.

Comment: @JAL See edit above

Comment: @I'L'I see edit